# How can I set the components of my JFrame to be organized neatly instead of jammed together?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

My credit card program uses JFrames and all the Panel/Text/Label stuff and I am having trouble with understanding Layouts. How can I modify the components of my Jframe/label to make them look something like this? (randomly pulled a form off of Google):

[image]
<sub>(source: [patterntap.com](http://patterntap.com/sites/default/files/originalpatterns/1/4/149048292149eb1edf4a215.png))</sub>

Now my "form" doesn't really look anything like this, nor have I tried to make it look like this. I tried reading about Layouts and I don't really get the specifics of it.

Currently my program just kinda blobs all the components on top of eachother, and if the components hit the end of the JFrame it starts a new line.

So, my question is how do I orgnize my JFrame's components to look neat like the image? Here is a little snippet of my code, I can add more if need be:

```
   public CreditGraphics() {



      frame = new JFrame("MES Banking App");
      panel = new JPanel();
      label = new JLabel();
      cardTypes = new String[4];
      cardTypes[0] = "Visa";
      cardTypes[1] = "American Express";
      cardTypes[2] = "Master Card";
      cardTypes[3] = "";
      cardTypesDD = new JComboBox(cardTypes);
      cardTypesDD.setSelectedIndex(3);


      text = new JTextField(16);

      panel.add(label);
      panel.add(cardTypesDD);
      panel.add(text);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true); 



      label.setText("<html>Please enter your credit card <br> 'Master Card' 'Visa' or 'American Express'</html>");
```

Comment: Have you followed the Swing part of the Oracle Java Tutorial?

Comment: use a WYSIWYG editor. Eclipse and Netbeans both have one. Then when you understand how it works you can start coding yours from scratch.

Comment: ^ I have no idea what WYSIWYG is...

Comment: And @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen where specifically in the Swing tutorial is it? (there's a ton of sections in there). thank you.

Comment: Choose an appropriate layout manager for each section of the u then combine these sections together with another layout manager which meets your needs [Layout out components within a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you elaborate please? i can use multiple LMs?

Comment: IMHO form editors are a bad idea for anyone who has little or no knowledge of how Swing layouts work. They can encourage bad habits and restrict the code to a single development environment, which may not be suitable in a team environment

Comment: Separate each area of your ui into a separate container, each container can have its own layout manager, to is what is commonly known as compound layouts, which allows you te ability to isolate each section and focus on its individual, special, requirements

Comment: I believe [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will provide you with some approximation of your sample.

Comment: I would suggest the "Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container"  part to learn about layout managers.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break down you form into functional components, not only those areas that relate to each other and would required individual management from the perspective of the application, but also from the point of view of differences in layout requirements.

You should then focus on the individual layout requirements of these sections within their own component space and finally add all this components back to a single container for the final layout.

Let's take your example and break it down into "functional" areas of responsibility.  The following is an example of prototyping (where you might have screen designed by a designer) or more commonly, napkin designing, where you sketch out your ideas on paper...

[image: Form]

There are at least five key areas of the form, which have their own layout requirements.  Now you "could" try and get all this to work within a single container/layout manager, but as the requirements of the form increase in complexity, so does the management of the layout...

[image: Part 01]

There are at least two possibilities for this section, you could use a `GridLayout`, so long as you set the requirements of the individual components to align correctly or a `GridBagLayout`, which would provide you with finer control over the positioning of the two elements...

[image: Part 02]

You could use a `GridBagLayout`, but that might be overkill in this situation, this could be achieved simply with a `BorderLayout`

[image: Part 04]

I might be tempted to use a `BorderLayout` here as well, but you could actually use a `FlowLayout` anchored to the `LEFT` and achieve the same result with less configuration...

[image: Part 04A]
[image: Part 04B]

Now, this is interesting, you have a number of choices here, you could separate the layout requirements of the header and the buttons, which would provide simplicity in the layout configuration, but you have two more components which would need to be combined to form the base component for this section, not a particular issue, but a consideration...

Or you could use a `TitledBorder` to apply the section header around a `FlowLayout`, anchored to the `LEFT`

Or use a `GridBagLayout`, allowing the header to expand across the remaining columns...

[image: Part 05]

This section is simply asking for a `GridBagLayout`, as each component wants to maintain a different size, but your also have multiple rows of components

[image: Part 06]

And, without a doubt, this section is asking for `GridBagLayout`.  It wants the functionality of the components been laid out in a grid pattern, but with the flexibility to define variable spacing between the components as well as variable sizes of the components.

Some components will need to expand multiple columns as well.

### Passing thoughts

The decision of which layout manager comes down a lot to the capabilities of the components you are laying out.  For example, if the component been used, can't align it's content to a given edge, then `GridLayout` may not be a suitable layout manager as will lose the flexibility of alignment (`GridLayout` will allow the content to center within the allotted grid)

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details on the various layout managers...

Comment: Hope it gives you some ideas ;)

Comment: This stuff is great! Easy to use too! My display looks awesome now, thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the Window Builder add-on if you’re using Eclipse. This tool will help you with many aspects of Swing. Learn by doing.

[WindowBuilder Dowload Link](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php)

Comment: IMHO form editors are a bad idea for anyone who has little or no knowledge of how Swing layouts work. They can encourage bad habits and restrict the code to a single development environment, which may not be suitable in a team environment - Without an appreciation of how Layout Managers work and how to combine them a user is only likely generate bad habits which will be hard to undo (yes I use form editors, but I've been building UI's by hand for 15+ years). WindowsBuilder is also a pain, as it seems to default to `null` layouts, which causes no end of issues

Comment: I understand and appreciate your comment. I’m new to this all and I was having trouble understanding how the layouts worked myself. WindowBuilder helped me understand the layouts visually. I thought it was a good learning aid which is why I suggested it. Clearly I’m incorrect.